# How to show project explorer pane on right side of screen

Tags: wing-ide

I recently switched to Wing Pro from Visual Studio.  Today my Wing IDE opened without the project explorer pane on the right side showing -- it's called project explorer in Visual Studio, I think it's called the same in Wing.  It's the listing of all project files.

I have looked all over the documentation and options but I haven't found where to make it show again.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

If no tools at all are showing, you have have pressed Shift-F2 (Maximize Editort Area) and can press that again to re-show them.  Or, just choose Project from the Tools menu and it should show the tool regardless of what display mode you're in.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Unfortunately, that doesn't bring up the Project Explorer pane on the right side of the screen.  I can still open each file with File - Open from Project, but I want the explorer pane on the right side because it's easier to use.

Comment: If it's on the left, then right-click on the tool tab and select Move Toolbox to Right.   You can also drag tool tabs from toolbox to toolbox our out of the window or back into a window, etc.